# very strange jquery issue

Tags: ajax, jquery, jquery-masonry

I am trying to run a function on page load but its not working. I've added it in every place I can think of and the **ONLY** thing that works is:

```
$("html").mousemove(function(event) {
    $('#project_thumbs_container').masonry('reload');
});
```

I've tried delays but I have resorted to the hacky above method :(

Does anyone have any suggestions as to why my function won't run?

UPDATE:

I am using masonry for jquery. My problem is when I load a page that uses masonry with ajax, it shows them in a single column. `$('#project_thumbs_container').masonry('reload');` resets it properly, but it only works using the above `mousemove` method.

Comment: Did you try adding code into the ajax callback to set up masonry? If you could share that part of your code, we could help you better.

Comment: I'm using pjax -- I've placed the code in so many places and for some reason that mousemove is the only thing that works.

Comment: Are you doing a lot of ajax calls? or just one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless someone has a better answer, I just put the code in my `fadeIn();` snippet after ajax call is complete:

```
this.fadeIn('slow', function() {
  $('#project_thumbs_container').masonry('reload');
});
```

Seems to work.

Comment: This is exactly what my advice to you was... how could I have improved my answer for you to accept it?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have one of two problems:

1) Malformed HTML which is causing an error, which isn't allowing the code to parse correctly when using the document onReady syntax: $(function() { ... });

2) Masonry might be loading asynchronously, which means that the "onReady" callback might not be the one that you want to be using. Your Ajax call would look more like this:

```
$('body').load('index.html', function() {
  $('#project_thumbs_container').masonry();
});
```

Comment: Or, if I'm understanding your latest comment correctly and you're using pjax, more like: `$.pjax( { success: function() { ... } } );` adding your other options, and replacing the ellipsis with the code in the function in my answer.

Comment: Error thrown from:  `if ( typeof options.container !== 'string') { throw "pjax container must be a string selector!" }`

Comment: Ah, the first parameter should be the container: $.pjax('body', { success: function() { ... } } );

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#project_thumbs_container').masonry('reload');
});
```

You can put this code anywhere on the page and it should work, as long as the dependencies have already been loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Just put your function in this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
  // your function 
});
```

when your page load the function will execute